# What's the difference between Unmaximize and UnmaximizeFull in Openbox?

Tags: openbox

The window manager *Openbox* (which is, for example, used by *Lubuntu 20.04*) allows us to define custom key bindings with desired actions. One such action is "Unmaximize" (as covered in the [documentation](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Actions#Unmaximize)). A couple of sources present examples using an action called "UnmaximizeFull" (e.g., [here](https://10wontips.blogspot.com/2020/09/get-back-standard-window-snapping-in.html), [there](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/how-to-resize-windows-using-hot-keys-to-fill-50-of-the-screen/1189/2), and also on the [openbox](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:WindowsInteractionWithWindowsKey) website itself). However, that action is not documented. So, does anybody know the difference between "Unmaximize" and "UnmaximizeFull"?

I tought, that maybe "UnmaximizeFull" is an alias for "Unmaximize" with the *direction* option set to "both", but that would be redundant since "both" is the default value anyway.

Other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on openbox documentation ([url](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Actions)) UnmaximizeFull existed in an older version (3.4, [url](http://openbox.org/wiki/?title=Help:Actions&oldid=2410#UnmaximizeFull)) and doesn't exist in the latest version as of now (3.6)

Comment: You are right - however, it seems that "UnmaximizeFull" indeed does still -unofficially- exist in Openbox 3.6 (presumably it was kept for backwards compatibility, the documentation says that the old syntax should still work in the newest version).